# Difference between initialization of final class variable

Tags: java, class, variables, initialization, final

I just tried out to set a variable, showing me that the super constructor has been finished without wasting my code.
So I remembered how class variables are initialized; after the super constructor but before the class constructor.
But there is something strange if you look at this example:

```
public class Init {

    public Init() {
        System.out.println("Init instance of " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println("syso Init:");
        this.syso(false);
    }

    protected void syso(boolean childCall) {
        System.out.println("should not be printed because the method is overwitten");
    }

    public static class Child extends Init {

        private final boolean finalTrueA = true;
        private final boolean finalTrueB;
        private final boolean finalTrueC;

        private boolean nonFinalTrueA = true;
        private boolean nonFinalTrueB;
        private boolean nonFinalTrueC;

        {
            this.finalTrueB = true;
            this.nonFinalTrueB = true;
        }

        public Child() {
            super();
            this.finalTrueC = true;
            this.nonFinalTrueC = true;

            System.out.println("\n\nsyso Child:");
            this.syso(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void syso(boolean childCall) {
            System.out.println("finalTrueA " + this.finalTrueA + " should be " + childCall);
            System.out.println("finalTrueB " + this.finalTrueB + " should be " + childCall);
            System.out.println("finalTrueC " + this.finalTrueC + " should be " + childCall);

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("nonFinalTrueA " + this.nonFinalTrueA + " should be " + childCall);
            System.out.println("nonFinalTrueB " + this.nonFinalTrueB + " should be " + childCall);
            System.out.println("nonFinalTrueC " + this.nonFinalTrueC + " should be " + childCall);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Child child = new Child();
    }

}
```

which has the following output:

```
Init instance of Child
syso Init:
finalTrueA true should be false // <-- why??????????
finalTrueB false should be false
finalTrueC false should be false

nonFinalTrueA false should be false
nonFinalTrueB false should be false
nonFinalTrueC false should be false


syso Child:
finalTrueA true should be true
finalTrueB true should be true
finalTrueC true should be true

nonFinalTrueA true should be true
nonFinalTrueB true should be true
nonFinalTrueC true should be true
```

This effect can be seen on the eclipse output as well as on running the class with javac.
But the eclipse debugger shows the correct value of *finalTrueA* within the super constructor call of the syso method.

So my question: Is this effect correct, that the different initialization results in different behaviour of the static fields and this is a bug of the eclipse debugger, or is this behaviour incorrect and it is a bug of java???

Comment: Interesting. It looks like this only affects `final` fields which have an initializer using a compile-time constant value.

Comment: This behavior is correct though not every programmer is aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

Every `final` variable which is immediately assigned with a compile-time constant and has a primitive or `String` type is a compile-time constant as well and its value will be inlined *at compile-time* when used in an expression context. This does apply to *all* variables, not only `static`. Consider the following (valid) code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  final int zero=0, one=zero+1, two=one+one, three=two+one;
  switch(args.length)
  {
    case zero: System.out.println("no args"); break;
    case one: System.out.println("one arg"); break;
    case two: System.out.println("two args"); break;
    case three: System.out.println("three args");
  }
}
```

Here, the local variables `zero`, `one`, `two`, and `three` are compile-time constants and hence even allowed as `switch case` labels…

In you case the value of `this.finalTrueA` inlined at compile-time and hence will be `true` even when invoked from the super-constructor.

Answer (score 0):

All `final` variables should be assigned during compile time. Either via `static initializer` or `in the constructor` or in the class itself.

See extract from [jls](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#35962)

```
It is a compile-time error if a blank final (§4.12.4) class variable is not definitely
assigned (§16.8) by a static initializer (§8.7) of the class in which it is declared.

A blank final instance variable must be definitely assigned (§16.9) at the end of every
constructor (§8.8) of the class in which it is declared; otherwise a compile-time error occurs
```

Based on the this, the variable `finalTrueA` is set to `true` at the time of compilation itself and thats why you see `true`.